# How To Make it wait until everything finish until next iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronization, settimeout

so i have this function here which i use to iterate Syllables which is Array of object

```
function showImagesByPairAtInterval(Syllables, interval, index) {
            index = index || 0;
            let slice = Syllables[index];
            nextIndex = index + 1;
            drawimagesonCanvas(slice.Url1, slice.Url2);//not finishing

            if (nextIndex <= Syllables.length - 1) {
                syllable_text.html(slice.The_Syl);

                setTimeout(showImagesByPairAtInterval.bind(
                    null,
                    Syllables,
                    interval,
                    nextIndex
                ), interval);
            }
            else {
                explain.html("Try Me Again");
                syllable_text.html("<br/>");
                $('#translate_button').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
```

What the problem is `drawimagesonCanvas` not been able to finish its work and it goes to next iteration after `interval` time

Here is `drawimagesonCanvas` code:

```
 function drawimagesonCanvas(url1,url2)
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_images");

        var IsBoth = (url2=="null");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


        if (!IsBoth) {
                img1.onload = function () {
                    context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 150, 350);

                };
                img1.src = api + url1;

                img2.onload = function () {
                    context.drawImage(img2, 150, 0, 150, 350);
                };
                img2.src = api + url2;
        }
        else
        {
            img1.onload=function(){

            context.drawImage(img1,0,0,300,350);
            }
            img1.src = api + url1;

        }
```

is there a way to make this problem disappear make a notice that the images is on the server Online and it's not local

Comment: you need to wait for the onload events to fire, but seeing as there could be one or two, it's not as simple as adding a callback to drawImagesonCanvas. Seeing as you are already using ES6 syntax, I imagine you would be able to use Promises - somethng to consider anyway

Comment: i'm really a beginner in JavaScript world is there a way to make alternative the code above to at least make it happen

Comment: Something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2oau2vg/)

Comment: I' Going to admit it this code right here really opens to me a variety of ways to accomplish procedures in the future thank u really that works like a charm you are the best my friend please make it an answer so i can up-vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a callback to `drawimagesonCanvas`, however as you may be waiting for one or two images, this complicates using a callback, not impossible, just (in my opinion) messy

Using Promises for this would be a cleaner solution.

Firstly, I've created a function, `loadImage` which returns a Promise that resolves once the image is loaded. This way, I can use Promise.all when there's two images, and just return the promise from `loadImage` when there's only one

Note, I've also changed the logic of `IsBoth` to be more "correct", i.e. IsBoth is TRUE when there are two images to load.

`drawimagesonCanvas` returns a Promise that resolves once the image(s) complete, in .then you check if more processing needs to be done, and call `drawimagesonCanvas` using setTimeout as you do in your code.

```
function drawimagesonCanvas(url1, url2) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_images");
    var IsBoth = (url2 != "null");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let loadImage = (url, x, y, w, h) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener('load', () => {
            context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
            resolve();
        });
        img.src = url;
    });
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (IsBoth) {
        return Promise.all([
            loadImage(api + url1, 0, 0, 150, 350),
            loadImage(api + url2, 150, 0, 150, 350)
        ]);
    } else {
        return loadImage(api + url1, 0, 0, 300, 350);
    }
}

function showImagesByPairAtInterval(Syllables, interval, index) {
    index = index || 0;
    let slice = Syllables[index];
    nextIndex = index + 1;
    drawimagesonCanvas(slice.Url1, slice.Url2)
    .then(() => {
        if (nextIndex <= Syllables.length - 1) {
            syllable_text.html(slice.The_Syl);
            setTimeout(showImagesByPairAtInterval.bind(
                null,
                Syllables,
                interval,
                nextIndex
            ), interval);
        } else {
            explain.html("Try Me Again");
            syllable_text.html("<br/>");
            $('#translate_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Any Idea How To make the canvas draw the two images at once not img1 then img2?

Comment: Javascript can't do two things simultaneously like that

Comment: Ok Thank you very much